# Show loading div on every jquery-ajax call

Tags: jquery

I have a web application in asp.net with lots of jquery-ajax call.
I have put a div on my master page and on every call I am showing on div as follows.

```
function updateInformation() {
$("#loading").show();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "url..",
    data: { "CustMobile": a, "CustName": b, "CustEmail": c },
    success: function (data) {
        $("#loading").hide();
        //do some processing
    },
    error: function () {
        $("#loading").hide();
    }
});}
```

My all jQuery functions are written in a single .js file.
Is there any way by which for every jquery-ajax call I can show the updating div.

I know that there are two global function ajaxStart & ajaxStop.
But will they affect my existing jquery call.