# jquery loading screen on ajax call

Tags: html, ajax, jquery

I would like to show a loading screen in my web application, whenever an ajax call is made with jquery.

Right now, various ajax calls are made: $.getJSON, $.post, $.ajaxFileupload, ...

a **Success** function is attached to it, that does away with the "loading" screen.

How can I do this in a general way, so a loading screen is shown automatically for each call?

The same question was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119506/show-loading-div-on-every-jquery-ajax-call), but no reply was given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [$.ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [$.ajaxStop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) methods:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    // Show loading dialog
  });
  $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    // Hide loading dialog
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend : callback,
    complete : anotherCallback
});
```

Replace the callback with the function you want to attach  to  the event.